# Separate client js for each module in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the modular folder structure shown [here](http://vimeo.com/56166857) by tjholowaychuk.

Is it somehow possible to also have a separate client JS in each of these modules? Currently all my client JS is in the `/assets/js` folder, but it would be nice to have a JS file in the module instead.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it, the best solution for me seems to be to put the client js under `lib/module/client/`, and then just use this path in the script tag. This way I can have a client js file for each module.